# Como criar ordenação com relacionamento de vários níveis no laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel

Eu realizei várias pesquisas para encontrar uma solução, porém só encontrei algumas bibliotecas que realizam a ordenação com apenas 1 nível.

```
$anuncios = Anuncio::with(['veiculo' => function($q){
        $q->orderBy('nome', 'asc');
    }]);
```

Dessa forma está ordenando apenas pela coluna "nome", mas eu preciso ordenar pela coluna de outra tabela com relacionamento, por exemplo, "veiculo.marca.nome". Existe uma biblioteca que disponibiliza esse funcionamento ou um código que poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Coloque esses models na pergunta e os relacionamentos.

Comment: Vamos supor que tenho os seguintes Models: Paises, estados e cidades. Tenho uma listagem com todas as cidades de todos os países. Como ordenar as cidades a partir do nome dos países?

Answer (score 0):

Eu aconselho a fazer da seguinte forma.

```
$transformer = function(Anuncio $anuncio) {

$anuncios = $anuncio->veiculo->marca->nome;

 return $anuncios->orderBy('nome');
}
```

Obs. Não sei como estão suas relações, mas acredito que já seja possivel chegar por anuncio no valor de nome.

Comment: Em que lugar ficaria esta função? Dentro do controller?

Comment: Sim, o que eu fiz foi pegar o seu codigo e fiz uma collection, dessa forma fica mais facil de trabalhar os dados, no meu entendimento.

Comment: De certa forma, assim estaremos ordenando a collection e não o builder propriamente dito. Correto? Isso não pode trazer problemas de desempenho? Há algum exemplo de como fazer essa ordenação com paginação?

Comment: Pelo que vi do codigo não deve ser algo muito pesado, então logo isso deve resolver, caso chegue a crescer o ideal seria quebrar isso em serviços.Eu faria assim pelo menos.